# remove part of name query MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

this is my record in database
[Dynamic Keyword In C# 4.0 - Part 3](ftp://myftp.co/ftp/Learning/Programming/C_/2000-C_-projects-[www.EhsanAvr.Com]/Dynamic%20Keyword%20In%20C#%204.0%20-%20Part%203.zip)

now i want edit this name with query to
[Dynamic Keyword In C# 4.0 - Part 3](ftp://myftp.co/Learning/Programming/C_/2000-C_-projects-[www.EhsanAvr.Com]/Dynamic%20Keyword%20In%20C#%204.0%20-%20Part%203.zip)

as u seen I want to remove `ftp/` after domain address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the REPLACE(str, find_string, replace_with) build in FUNCTION

```
SELECT REPLACE(`link_field`, '/ftp/', '/') AS `link` FROM `table`;
```

see more info and examples in

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php